# Skip a value in do-while loop

Tags: php, do-while

I've got a script that sets up a array of dates which form a dropdown. The array is set up by some variables about the current date and an fixed offset for the last date (two weeks). Stripped down this is what it looks like:

```
public function getDatesOptionArray()
{
    $datesArray = array();
    $displayDate = Mage::getModel('core/locale')->storeDate();
    $displayDate->add($this->_startDaysOffset, Zend_Date::DAY);
    $dayOffset = $this->_startDaysOffset;

    do
    {
        $dayofweek = date('w', strtotime($displayDate->toString(Varien_Date::DATE_INTERNAL_FORMAT)));

        $datesArray[$displayDate->toString(Varien_Date::DATE_INTERNAL_FORMAT)] = Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($displayDate, Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_FULL);
        $displayDate->add('1', Zend_Date::DAY);
        $dayOffset++;

    } while ($dayOffset <= $this->_endDaysOffset);

    return $datesArray;
}
```

The thing is I want to leave out all the 'Sunday' options, and I've got the `$dayofweek` variable for each, where sunday is 0. I've tried to wrap the whole thing inside the `do` function in an if-statement (`if $dayofweek !== 0`), set an `if ($dayofweek == 0) { continue;}` and every other trick I could think of, but I get only either of these results

- 1: Only the first date is shown
- 2: All dates until the first sunday are shown, none after that
- 3: All dates are shown

I think I might be missing the point on the do-while loop; how do I exclude `if $dayofweek == 0`?

Comment: Unrelated optimization: why not change `$displayDate->add($this->_startDaysOffset, Zend_Date::DAY); $dayOffset = $this->_startDaysOffset;` around, so it becomes `$dayOffset = $this->_startDaysOffset; $displayDate->add($dayOffset, Zend_Date::DAY);`? Also, any particular reason for the `do { } while` instead of a good'ol `for`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me is something like this, i use while because Do...While(...) the first time it will not check your condition you'll enter your loop at last 1 time, and when you use while(...){} every time your program will check your condition

```
public function getDatesOptionArray()
{
  $datesArray = array();
  $displayDate = Mage::getModel('core/locale')->storeDate();
  $displayDate->add($this->_startDaysOffset, Zend_Date::DAY);
  $dayOffset = $this->_startDaysOffset;


  while ($dayOffset <= $this->_endDaysOffset)
  {
   $dayofweek = date('w', strtotime($displayDate->toString(Varien_Date::DATE_INTERNAL_FORMAT)));
   if ($dayofweek != 0) {
      $datesArray[$displayDate->toString(Varien_Date::DATE_INTERNAL_FORMAT)] = Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($displayDate, Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_FULL);
    }
    $displayDate->add('1', Zend_Date::DAY);

    $dayOffset++;
  }
  return $datesArray;
}
```

Comment: When I try to structure it like that, it can't find the variable $dayofweek because it is inside the while-loop. Take it out of there, and all the values for the loop return todays date..

Comment: @AlexTimmer I change the code, I met the  `$dayofweek` before the If

Comment: Hmm, this has the same effect as some other things I tried; it shows the coming dates correctly until the first sunday. After that, it treats all other dates as sunday. I logged both if/else outputs: weekday4,weekday5,weekday6,sunday0,sunday0,sunday0,sunday0,sunday0,sunday0,sunday0,sunday0,sunday0,sunday0,sunday0

Comment: @AlexTimmer Because your dayofweek depend displayDate, if your displaydate don't +1 your dayofweek will not change

Comment: @AlexTimmer I change the code, the display date will add 1 everytime now

Comment: That did the trick. It's propably not the best practice, but you know how things go; it'll have to do for now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Let say the array is

```
$date = array(
    2017-10-12,
    2017-10-13,
    2017-10-14,
    2017-10-15,
    2017-10-16,
    2017-10-17,
    2017-10-18,
    2017-10-19,
    2017-10-20,
    2017-10-21,
    2017-10-22,
    2017-10-23,
    2017-10-24,
    2017-10-25
);
```

Now do this for remove sunday's dates

```
$i=0;
do{
    if(date('w',strtotime($date[$i]))>0) $dateArray[] = $date[$i];
    $i++;
} while ($i<count($date));
echo "<pre>";print_r($dateArray);
return $datesArray;
```

$dateArray will give you dates without sundays.